# Is it possible to add an image on top of a ListView?

Tags: android

Like the title says, is it possible? My purpose is to make a little logo on top of the ListView centered in the view pane

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about adding a header to the `ListView`? See [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29).

Comment: Cheers! didn't notice that one :)